# Interface (semi) graphically with SSH

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, gui

Is there any way I can use the `ssh` command to interface somewhat graphically throught the terminal.

Example: I have my laptop while I'm lying in bed. I want to watch the colbert report on my desktop across the room. Is there any way I can use terminal commands to do things like send key-signals (command-space) etc. to the linux machine across the room?

I don't really want to install logmein or anything like that.

Any info on this would be super helpful.

Comment: You could always log on to the desktop, export the display to your laptop and view the film there. Your video player would still run on the server but it would appear on your laptop. If that will work for you let me know and I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some programs have CLI interfaces (e.g. `rhythmbox-client`), can have their executable send commands to an already-running instance (e.g. `totem`), or can react to various D-Bus calls (i.e. `dbus-send`). See the documentation for the specific applications of interest for details.